# Fetch data from a SQLite View with CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, view, sqlite, core-data-migration

Is it possible with Core-Data to fetch data from a view ? (I mean a SQLite View)

On the first launch of my iOS app, I load data from a single SQLite file into my Core-Data store, but in this sqlite file, I also have a view. 
How can I handle this with Core-Data ?

I would like to be able to fetch data from this view.

Comment: You are not supposed to alter the format of the database file that Core Data uses. Could you trick Core Data into reading from a view by naming it the same as the tables Core Data is expecting? Maybe, but it won't be supported. Core Data is not meant to load arbitrary SQLite databases. Are you sure you need Core Data, or would it be more appropriate to use SQLite directly to access this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view is really nothing but a select statement. Just sync these separately using simple SQL strings. You can store them as FetchRequestTemplates in your Core Data model.